# MIME Type Warning in Google Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, iis-7, asp-classic

I generate a captcha image (as a .bmp) on the fly with a server side script (.asp).

It is included in a page as follows:

`<iframe id="commentCaptcha" height="20px" width="50px" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="/inc_captcha.asp">`

Everything works as it should.

The problem/Question is that I get the following warning in the google chrome console:

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/bmp: "/inc_captcha.asp".`

Here are the actual raw headers returned from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: image/bmp
Expires: Sun, 13 Jan 2013 03:11:36 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Sun, 13 Jan 2013 03:12:36 GMT
Connection: close
```

Is there any way I can prevent this warning?

Comment: If you save the captcha image to your computer and inspect with a hex viewer, does it have any non-BMP data at the start, e.g. blank lines?

Comment: I double checked this and found that the image is in good form and matches the BMP profile exactly. I tripple checked this by saving it as an image, then uploading that to my server. No warning message when it is loaded that way.  Any thoughts on where to go next? Could it be an IIS mime type setting? Could it be a chrome thing where it knows that the extension is .asp so it overrides the `image/bmp` content type?

Comment: Sorry, can't help further as I try to avoid BMP.

Comment: Thanks for looking anyway. I noticed that when I use it as the src attribute in an image tag, no error occurs, so that's the way I am going for now (instead of using the iframe). It is for a captcha implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the source of the `iframe` to a non-document mine-type is a little strange and not really the usual way of doing it.

Instead the `iframe` should have the `src` set to a `text/HTML` document, your image being an `<img>` within that document.

If it's just the image you're after, use the `<img>` tag in the parent document and dont use an `iframe` at all.

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is what I ended up implementing. Thanks for the info. I am still trying to understand why, even when just viewing the url in chrome or the image generating file itself, it still gives the warning.